# Why are some questions tagged with [untagged]?

Tags: support, tags

You can see them here: [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll clarify the process here, since this question got bumped and the full explanation isn't in an answer yet.

There is a periodic process that will remove any tag that *only has one instance* and *has lasted for 6 months*. If there are other tags on the question, it will just remove the tag. If it is the last tag on a question, though, that question will be marked with [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). The former is actually more dangerous, because it is more difficult to track and notice. But this is the origin of the tag.

You can prevent this easiest by simply asking another question that needs the same tag. As well, this is also a good reason that, when introducing a new tag that applies to old questions, you should find at least two candidates. As long as there are at least two instances, the automated process will not remove the tag from existing questions.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when the last tag on a question is removed.

Those probably happened when Jeff nuked the board-games tag.

Comment: I see. I had hoped it was some auto process that created it because the edit history wasn't helpful at all! `:)`

Comment: AFAIK removing the last tag on a question is something only the devs can do so I'm not surprised that it isn't very discoverable.

Comment: After some digging on MSO, I've found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) which I'm guessing is how it happened in this case.

Comment: Good to know about. I'm guessing we're going to be hit a bit harder by this than the larger sites like SO. I guess an administrative task for the editors out there is to retag the more interesting untagged questions. @yhw42

Comment: Sigh, some of them were legitimately tagged but now aren't it seems. Lame.

Comment: OK, I've retagged them all. Apparently "low use" tags, which includes tags for RPGs that don't have scads of questions here, get deleted from time to time so I reckon we'll see 'traveller' and "apocalypse-world" and other games get deleted again.  I guess that will teach people to use anything other than the most popular ones!

Comment: @mxyzplk It looks like it's tags that are used exactly once. I think we're the edge-case for this system... Works great on large sites where there are at least a couple questions about anything, not so hot on sites like this one where we might have only one question about a given game. I wonder if there are any easy ways to make it smarter... But I think the moral of the story here is that low-traffic systems should include the system name in the title or body.

Comment: @AceCalhoon I vote for body, because the tag already gets put in the title bar.