# Retagging untagged questions

Tags: support, tags

Could we retag our [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions on [main](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/), please?

The reasons they have become untagged are [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/922/2788), in short, *there is a periodic process that will remove any tag that only has one instance and has lasted for 6 months.*

Obviously some of these will want to be deleted, others just retagged.

Comment: I don't understand what action you're asking to be taken.

Comment: For instance, I found a question about torg that was tagged as [tag:untagged]. I re-tagged it as [tag:torg]

Comment: Don't ask fake questions just to get a second tag please.  Question seeding is not appropriate on this site; ask real questions about problems you face.

Comment: Agreed. FWIW I found the untagged torg question when I started writing my one, via the suggested question box.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good idea to periodically check for [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions.

There are currently 6 as of the time I am writing this.

Just as a reminder, any tag that only has one question for an entire 6 month period will be culled from the system as not useful, to avoid long term clutter of the tag system. If you feel strongly that a particular single use tag should stick around, make sure there are at least **two** questions with that tag.

See discussion at: [Should We Zap The Low-Occurrence Tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags)